# Impossible to select all_day_slots with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to create a calendar where my user can indicate his disponibilities. I have set up the calendar so there are allDaySlots available. They appear correctly on the calendar, but I can't select them. Is there anything special to specify in the select callback?

Is it also possible to set up fullcalendar so that when the user selects the allDaySlot, the whole row concerning that day appears as selected?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  var array_dispo = [];


  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView:  'agendaWeek',
    lang:         "fr",
    header:       false,
    timezone:     'local',
    minTime:      "08:00:00",
    columnFormat: 'dddd',
    selectHelper: true,
    selectable:   true,
    allDaySlot: true,

    select: function(start, end, allDay) {

      var eventData = {
        // allDay: allDay,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        block:  true,
        editable: true,
        backgroundColor: "#469278"
      };

      var mEnd = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
      var mStart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
      if (mEnd.isAfter(mStart, 'day')) {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
      } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
      console.log(eventData);
       var array_all_events = [];
       var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
       $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
           var day         = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd');
           var start_time  = moment(value.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = moment(value.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var slot        = {
              day: day,
              start_time: start_time,
              end_time: end_time,
            };
          array_all_events.push(slot);
          $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
      });
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
    },

    eventClick: function(event, element) {
      if(confirm('Voulez-vous supprimer cette dispo?')) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
        var array_all_events = [];
        var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        // console.log(all_events);
        $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
          // console.log(value.start["_d"]);
          // console.log(index);
           var day         = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd');
           var start_time  = moment(value.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = moment(value.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
             // var id          = value.unique_id["_i"];
             var slot        = {
                day: day,
                start_time: start_time,
                end_time: end_time,
              };
            array_all_events.push(slot);
            console.log(array_all_events.length);
            if (array_all_events.length == 0) {
              $("#dispo_array").val("");
            }
            else {
              $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
            }
        });



      }
    },
    eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
      // console.log(event);
      var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

    },

    selectOverlap: function(event) {
      return ! event.block;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I've made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xaLzo7g6/)

This snippet here:

```
...
 var mEnd = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
      var mStart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
      if (mEnd.isAfter(mStart, 'day')) {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
      } else {

...
```

is causing an immediate unselect on all-day events since the condition `mEnd > mStart` is always true for those.

if you change to

```
...

      var mEnd = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
      var mStart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);

      // just uncommented this:
      /*if (mEnd.isAfter(mStart, 'day')) {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
      } else*/ 

      {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
...
```

the all-day events get rendered properly. `title` is mandatory, so I added this.

Another approach would be to set the default event duration to `0` but I haven't tested that, see here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultAllDayEventDuration/

**EDIT**

have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xaLzo7g6/3/

Multiple things:

- moment events are mutable, thus need cloning befor modifying them
- timezone was set to "local" while moment is UTC, This resulted in a 2-hour shift in to the next day on all events. Setting that to "UTC" fixed the overlap in to the next day
- the logic of unselecting was removed entirely, since its unnecessary

from my perspective it now behaves as wanted: clicking on an allday slot or selecting any time frame always "selects" the entire day and blocks it

Comment: ok so then the relevant question becomes how do I set the allday event to start at my min_time and end at my max_time

Comment: all-day events are untimed events. An event, starting at min and ending at max_timec an't be an all-day event, that's a contradiction. Either you have an all-day event or you have a particular start and end time.

Comment: But as you say: " it is causing an immediate unselect on all-day events since the condition `mEnd > mStart` is always true for those." And when I am checking the object in the console a mStart & mEnd specify a start and end time

Comment: Yes, true, but you may read the docs. If the property "allDay" is set to true, it's treated __as if__ these start and end times are not set. It's indeed a bit confusing as of this doumentation: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ and as it's not fully clear what you are trying to achieve when user selects an all-day slot, I've just only made it "selectable" in my example.

Comment: Probably a question of definition: an event from 00:00 to 23:59 lasts exactly one day but it is __NOT__ an "all-day" event in the understanding of fullcalendar (and even not in outlook and in Google Calendar). An "all day event" is an event which has "no particular start or end time" on the given day.

Comment: Ok then I believe what I want is actually set the `allDay to false` in `eventData` (which does actually select the all day column when I click on it, which is what I wanted to do). Problem is : it still creates me an event that overlaps on two days (starts at 00:00 and finishes at 00:00) which still doesnt match my non multiple day event condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91953/discussion-between-david-geismar-and-axel-amthor).

Comment: The time "00:00" per definition belongs to the "new" or "next" day. A time period "00:00 - 00:00" therefor is a two-days period by definition. One single day is "00:00 - 23:59:59.999". Strange and I always stumble in to this also. But the "boundary" between two days has no period, so it's a definition question.